# Gatsbyjs - How to pull in GraphQL data with Material UI Lib

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

Am New to Frontend Dev . Learning Gatsbyjs with Material UI library.
I am trying to create a new page with the materialui gatsby started @

[Material UI Gatsby Starter](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/gatsby)

Now, when i try creating a new page using GraphQL  , and try to print the data, am seeing an error .
Not sure how to push the data from graphQl

This is the code for my new  page . Basically am trying to print the data retrieved from GraphQL on the page .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';


const styles = {

  };

const page2 = (props,{data}) => {
  const { classes } = props;

    return (
      <div>
                Hello  {data.site.siteMetadata.title}

  <Button className={classes.button}>Default</Button>

  </div>
)

}

export default withStyles(styles)(page2);

export const query = graphql`
  query AboutTitleQuery {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
    title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Error is :: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'site' of undefined

The Query runs fine when run in GraphiQL

```
{
  "data": {
    "site": {
      "siteMetadata": {
        "title": "Gatsby Default Starter"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Attaching Screenshot 
[image]

Comment: You might have had an error with the syntax when you booted `gatsby develop` that is fixed now. Try restarting `gatsby develop`. If that doesn't work, try stopping it, removing `.cache` and starting again. Watch the terminal output for any errors or warnings.

Comment: Tried rerunning npm install . Same Error . Where do i find the .cache file ? 
GraphQl IDE is detecting the change . Its just not reflecting on the Render method .Not sure why . DO I have any error with the syntax for                 
    Hello  {data.site.siteMetadata.title}

Comment: Okay, reinstalling dependencies isn't going to help you here. Gatsby creates the `.cache` folder in your project root. You can run `rm -rf .cache` from your project root (i.e. where you run `gatsby develop` from) if you're on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are not destructuring the `props` correctly, try this:

```
const page2 = ({ data, classes }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Hello {data.site.siteMetadata.title}
      <Button className={classes.button}>Default</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Cool , That works !
Have a question , why doesn't it work when i retrieve it as props and assign to classes in a separate question ? 

const page2 = ({props,data}) => {
 const { classes } = props;

Comment: Because that tries to get the `props` property of `this.props`, which is not defined. But what you can do is use spread like `({ data, ...props })`.